# Try to connect to Informix database Cisco UCCX with unix ODBC - no success

Tags: informix, cisco

Try to use Informix driver to connect over ODBC to Cisco UCCX database. Install IBM informix SDK
Files of SDK /opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK

**odbcinst -j**

```
unixODBC 2.3.9
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/alexniko/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
```

**odbc.ini**

```
[ODBC Data Sources]
uccx
uccx2

[uccx]
DRIVER={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)}
UID=uccxhruser
PWD=TrebuSHet{}123
DATABASE=db_cra
HOST=uccx-01.fccps.local
SERVER=uccx_01_uccx
SERVICE=1504
PROTOCOL=onsoctcp
CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8
DB_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8

[uccx2]
DRIVER={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER 2 (64-bit)}
UID=uccxhruser
PWD=TrebuShet{}123
DATABASE=db_cra
HOST=uccx-02.fccps.local
SERVER=uccx_02_uccx
SERVICE=1504
PROTOCOL=onsoctcp
CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8
DB_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8
```

**odbcinst.ini**

```
[IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)]
Driver=/opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK/lib/cli/iclis09b.so
Description=IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER
UID=uccxhruser
PWD=TrebuShet{}123
DATABASE=db_cra
HOST=uccx-01.fccps.local
SERVER=uccx_01_uccx
SERVICE=1504
PROTOCOL=onsoctcp
CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8
DB_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8

[IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER 2 (64-bit)]
Driver=/opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK/lib/cli/iclis09b.so
Description=IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER
UID=uccxhruser
PWD=TrebuShet{}123
DATABASE=db_cra
HOST=uccx-02.fccps.local
SERVER=uccx_02_uccx
SERVICE=1504
PROTOCOL=onsoctcp
CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8
DB_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8
```

ldd -v /opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK/lib/cli/iclis09b.so
Have no error

Connecttion string in python:

```
SERVICE=1504;PROTOCOL=onsoctcp;
CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8;DB_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8;
DRIVER=IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit);
UID=uccxhruser;PWD=TrebuShet{}123;
DATABASE=db_cra;
HOST=uccx-01.fccps.local;
SERVER=uccx_01_uccx;
```

when I try to connect receive error:

```
Can't open lib '/opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK/lib/cli/iclis09b.so' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Trying to check driver work with isql -v uccx - receive error

```
[IM002][unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found and no default driver specified
[ISQL]ERROR: Could not SQLConnect
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Is there any chance that you've actually got a 32-bit ODBC client installed?  Is the file `/opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK/lib/cli/iclis09b.so` a 32-bit shared object or a 64-bit shared object?  (What does running `file /opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK/lib/cli/iclis09b.so` say?) It's fairly implausible, but you've covered a lot of bases.  What does running `ldd /opt/IBM/Informix_Client-SDK/lib/cli/iclis09b.so` say?  Is there any danger that the code running the ODBC connection is using `chroot`?  (Again, fairly improbable.) What do you have set in the `$LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Have you tried with UnixODBC ISQL? That would be my first choice to validate that the Informix ODBC is working.  Also, as mentioned before, make sure all executables and libraries are the same (32/64).  It shouldn't be needed, but I know some process don't inherit LD_LIBRARY_PATH, so as last resort, you can always add $INFORMIXDIR/lib:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/esql:$INFORMIXDIR/lib/cli to the global config path.